# What is the difference between the alphabet set and the support of a random variable?

Tags: probability, set-theory

I'm having trouble identifying the differences between the two. Are they equivalent? Here's the definitions from [http://www.stat.yale.edu/~yw562/teaching/itlectures.pdf](http://www.stat.yale.edu/%7Eyw562/teaching/itlectures.pdf)
[image: Here's the definitions from http://www.stat.yale.edu/~yw562/teaching/itlectures.pdf]

Comment: Your question needs more context. Could you provide an example?

Comment: @mhdadk edited for clarity

Comment: Think of the integers $\geq 0$ combined with a Binomial$(n,p)$ distribution as fitting the first definition.  However, the support of such a Binomial distribution is the set of integers in $\{0, \dots, n\}$, as the probability of seeing an observation $>n$ equals $0$.

Comment: @jbowman makes sense - thank you!

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only distinction being made here is that the probabilities of some of the atoms can be zero, whereas by definition an atom with zero probability is not in the support.  One reason why this quotation is problematic is that the first bullet point is not a good definition, because "the" alphabet is not completely defined.  Sure, the support is in any alphabet; but according to this definition, you can include up to a countable number of *arbitrary* elements of $X$ in the alphabet.

Comment: A glance at the source of this quotation indicates it's part of a "review."  The notation in that box is nonstandard and truly awful (for instance, it confuses vectors with sets).  It will be useful only for those who are already so familiar with these concepts that the errors of notation will not bother them. If that's not the case, be prepared for extreme frustration when trying to read this text!  If that is the case, it looks like worthwhile reading.

Comment: @whuber yeah that's the only difference I could see as well - that the alphabet may include elements with zero probability, whereas support strictly contains elements with non-zero probabilities.